# Hitting slow path when rendering raw pixel buffers

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, core-image, core-video

My OS X app generates lots of thumbnails of movies. I experimented a lot to come up with the right trade-offs between the cost of the thumbnail generation, and fast display. The current setup, which works quite well, consists of writing raw ARGB CVPixelBufferData to disk, and convert them into images later to display them (The thumbnails are very small, 100x100 max). The problem I'm having is that the images I generated in this way take a long time to render.

This is the code I use to convert the buffer data back to images:

```
        CGImageRef videoImage = NULL;
        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBufferOut = NULL;

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];

        if (imageData) {

            size_t width = [self.bufferAttributes[(__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
            size_t height = [self.bufferAttributes[(__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
            //size_t bytesPerRow = [self.bufferAttributes[(__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
            OSType pixelFormatType = [self.bufferAttributes[(__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey] unsignedIntValue];

            CVReturn ret = CVPixelBufferCreate(NULL, width, height, pixelFormatType, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef _Nullable)(self.bufferAttributes), &pixelBufferOut);

            if (ret == kCVReturnSuccess) {

                CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBufferOut, 0);
                void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBufferOut);
                memcpy(baseAddress, imageData.bytes, imageData.length);
                CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:pixelBufferOut];
                CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
                videoImage = [temporaryContext createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBufferOut), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBufferOut))];
                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBufferOut, 0);
            } else {

                //CFRelease(imgDataCF);
            }
        }

        if (videoImage) {
            images[count] = CFBridgingRelease(videoImage);
        } else {


        }

        CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBufferOut);
```

Rendering these images is much slower than, say, loading data of a png. I tried to copy the relevant instrument backtraces:

```
Running Time    Self (ms)       Symbol Name
5851.0ms   56.7%    0.0                      -[_NSScrollingConcurrentMainThreadSynchronizer _synchronize:completionHandler:]
5437.0ms   52.7%    0.0                       CA::Transaction::commit()
5428.0ms   52.6%    1.0                        CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
5297.0ms   51.4%    0.0                         CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*)
5289.0ms   51.3%    0.0                          CA::Render::prepare_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double)
5289.0ms   51.3%    0.0                           CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double)
5288.0ms   51.3%    0.0                            CA::Render::create_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int)
5278.0ms   51.2%    0.0                             CA::Render::(anonymous namespace)::create_image_by_rendering(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int)
5199.0ms   50.4%    0.0                              CGContextDrawImage
5197.0ms   50.4%    0.0                               ripc_DrawImage
5175.0ms   50.2%    1.0                                ripc_AcquireImage
5174.0ms   50.2%    0.0                                 CGSImageDataLock
5174.0ms   50.2%    4.0                                  img_data_lock
5048.0ms   48.9%    0.0                                   img_blocks_extent
5048.0ms   48.9%    0.0                                    img_blocks_create
5048.0ms   48.9%    0.0                                     FECIImageImageProvider::copyImageBlockSet(void*, CGImageProvider*, CGRect, CGSize)
5048.0ms   48.9%    0.0                                      FECIImageImageProvider::copyImageBlockSet_(CGImageProvider*, CGRect, CGSize)
5024.0ms   48.7%    0.0                                       FECIImageImageProvider::ensureData(CGColorSpace*, CGRect, CGSize, fe_bitmap_struct*, CGPoint*)
4670.0ms   45.3%    1.0                                        -[FEImage getBitmap:withContext:origin:transform:colorSpace:alreadyClampedToAlpha:]
4668.0ms   45.3%    0.0                                         -[FEImage(Internal) _renderWithContext:bounds:transform:colorSpace:format:premultiplied:setupCallback:finishCallback:callbackData:alreadyClampedToAlpha:]
4663.0ms   45.2%    1.0                                          FETreeContext::renderImage(FEImage*, CGRect, FEShape const*, CGAffineTransform, CGColorSpace*, FEFormat, bool, void (*)(FEContext*, void*, FEFormat), void (*)(FEContext*, void*), void*, signed char)
4571.0ms   44.3%    0.0                                           FETreeContext::renderImage_(FEImage*, CGRect, FEShape const*, CGAffineTransform, CGColorSpace*, FEFormat, bool, void (*)(FEContext*, void*, FEFormat), void (*)(FEContext*, void*), void*, bool)
4545.0ms   44.1%    1.0                                            FETreeContext::renderTree(FETreeNode*, FEShape const&, void (*)(FEContext*, void*, FEFormat), void (*)(FEContext*, void*), void*)
4532.0ms   43.9%    0.0                                             FETreeNode::render(FETreeContext*, FEShape const&, void (*)(FEContext*, void*, FEFormat), void (*)(FEContext*, void*), void*)
4529.0ms   43.9%    2.0                                              FETreeNode::render_(FETreeContext*, FEShape const*, void (*)(FEContext*, void*, FEFormat), void (*)(FEContext*, void*), void*)
4522.0ms   43.8%    3.0                                               FEApplyTreeNode::render2(FETreeContext*, FEShape const*, void (*)(FEContext*, void*, FEFormat), void (*)(FEContext*, void*), void*)
2659.0ms   25.8%    1.0                                                FEApplyTreeNode::render1(FETreeContext*, FEShape const&, fe_kernel_target_struct*, int, float*, FETreeTexture*)
1252.0ms   12.1%    0.0                                                 glBegin_Exec
1252.0ms   12.1%    0.0                                                  gleDoDrawDispatchCore
1250.0ms   12.1%    1.0                                                   gldUpdateDispatch
645.0ms    6.2% 0.0                                                    g575_LoadAndOptimizePipelinePrograms(GLDContextRec*, unsigned int*)
645.0ms    6.2% 0.0                                                     gpusLoadCurrentPipelinePrograms
645.0ms    6.2% 1.0                                                      glrUpdateCtxSysVertexProgram
623.0ms    6.0% 0.0                                                       GHAL3D::CPrivateStateProcessor::CreateVertexShader(GHAL3D::CVertexShader*)
580.0ms    5.6% 0.0                                                        GHAL3D::CGen6StateProcessorCache::CreateVertexShader(GHAL3D::HANDLE_TYPE)
579.0ms    5.6% 1.0                                                         GHAL3D::CStateCache<GHAL3D::SGen6VertexShaderKernelProgramCacheKey, GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgramCacheData>::PreAllocateData(GHAL3D::SGen6VertexShaderKernelProgramCacheKey const&, GHAL3D::HANDLE_TYPE&)
578.0ms    5.6% 0.0                                                          GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgramCacheData::Create(GHAL3D::CStateProcessorCache*, GHAL3D::SGen6VertexShaderKernelProgramCacheKey const&, GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgramCacheData*&)
578.0ms    5.6% 0.0                                                           GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgramCacheData::Initialize()
577.0ms    5.6% 2.0                                                            GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgram::Create(void const*, PLATFORM_STR, GHAL3D::CVertexShader const*, S3DKernelHardwareCapabilities const&, GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgram*&)
574.0ms    5.5% 0.0                                                             GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgram::Initialize()
567.0ms    5.5% 0.0                                                              GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgram::Build()
499.0ms    4.8% 0.0                                                               GHAL3D::CGen6VertexShaderKernelProgram::Compile(GHAL3D::SKernelCompilerControls const&)
393.0ms    3.8% 3.0                                                                GHAL3D::CGen4KernelFunctionList::VirtualRegistersToRegisters(GHAL3D::CGen4EURegisterAllocator*, bool, GHAL3D::CGen4ShaderDecomposer*, GHAL3D::CGen4ShaderSymbolTable*, S3DKernelHardwareCapabilities const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool&, unsigned int&, unsigned int&, unsigned int&, GHAL3D::SHADER_TYPE)
123.0ms    1.1% 2.0                                                                 GHAL3D::CGen4KernelFunctionList::ComputeLivenessSets(unsigned int, bool, bool)
105.0ms    1.0% 1.0                                                                  GHAL3D::CGen4LIRControlFlowGraph::ComputeLivenessSets(iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, unsigned int, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool&)
96.0ms    0.9%  77.0                                                                      GHAL3D::CGen4LIRBasicBlock::ComputeLivenessSets(iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>&, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, GHAL3D::CGen4LIRControlFlowGraph*, bool&, bool&)
6.0ms    0.0%   2.0                                                                    iSTD::CBitSet<GHAL3D::CAllocator>::Create(unsigned int)
3.0ms    0.0%   0.0                                                                     malloc
3.0ms    0.0%   0.0                                                                      malloc_zone_malloc
3.0ms    0.0%   2.0                                                                       szone_malloc_should_clear
1.0ms    0.0%   1.0                                                                        tiny_malloc_from_free_list
```

Any ideas on how I could improve the rendering time?